# How can I use uncountable nouns in resource routes with Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called Aircraft, inflected as uncountable, and it's
driving me nuts. What is the correct way to handle this in Rails 3 "beta
4"?

```
resources :aircraft do
  member do
    get :flights
  end
end

# Of course these work for some actions and not others.
match 'aircraft', :to => 'aircraft#index', :as => :aircraft
match 'aircraft/:id', :to => 'aircraft#show', :as => :aircraft_instance
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just:

```
resources :aircraft, :singular => :aircraft_instance
```

Then you `link_to` them like so:

```
link_to 'Singular aircraft', aircraft_instance_path(@aircraft)
link_to 'All aircraft', aircraft_path(@aircraft)
```

**Edit**

It looks like `beta4` thinks aircrafts in the plural of aircraft:

```
rails console
> :aircraft.to_s.pluralize
=> "aircrafts"
```

If you just put `resources :aircraft` into your routes, can you `link_to` both `aircraft_path(@aircraft)` and `aircrafts_path` successfully? If so, you may need to write an initializer for `ActiveSupport::Inflector` to define your own custom inflection.

Comment: It used to be that way. Now {"singular"=>:aircraft_instance} shows up in the request parameters. Yes... request parameters, as if I had submitted them with the browser.